# Website is responsive on my laptop, but not on phones or tablets

Tags: html, css

This is a problem with the website as a whole, not just one div or section. 
To make my website responsive, I am using media queries. To help me with responsive styling, I am using Grids.css. I set a media query as follows:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {


    .section-web-projects {   
        height: 290vh;
    }

       .skills div.col {
        width: 100%;    
    }

    .skills-div {

        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        padding-bottom: -20px;
        text-align:center;
        margin-right: 50px;
        margin-left: - 50px; 
        font-size: 100%;

    }  
  }
```

This corresponds to the following in html :

```
 <div class="row">              
    <h2 class="section-header"></h2>       
   </div>


             <div class="row">

              <h2 class="hireme-web"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit </h2> 


               <div class="skills">

                    <div class="col span-1-of-4">

                        <div class="skills-div">  
                            <h3> <i class="ion-iphone skills-div-icon"></i> <i class="ion-ios-monitor-outline skills-div-icon"></i>  <i class="ion-ipad skills-div-icon"></i> <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc et diam volutpat, eleifend ex vel, rutrum nisl. Morbi gravida, libero a imperdiet vehicula, ante erat pretium metus, in scelerisque velit elit tincidunt eros <br> <br> </h3>
                        </div>

                    </div>


        <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                  <div class="skills-div">  
                    <h3> <i class="ion-ios-locked-outline skills-div-icon"></i> <br>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc et diam volutpat, eleifend ex vel, rutrum nisl. Morbi gravida, libero a imperdiet vehicula, ante erat pretium metus, in scelerisque velit elit tincidunt eros <br> <br> </h3>
                </div>

        </div>

             </div> <!-- end of skills -->                             
    </div> <!-- end of row -->

</section>
```

And this is the corresponding styling without any media queries:

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}


.row {
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.skills {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;   
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}



.skills-div {


    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-align:left;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 90%;

}
```

Here is what it looks like on Google Nexus 4 at [384 px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTsd8.jpg):

Here is what it looks like on chrome window  at [400px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yXf2.jpg) . This is the effect I want and have encoded into the media query; but its not working.

Comment: Try removing "only" from your media query. Also make sure you've added the viewport meta tag to the head of your webpage `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: That worked! Post this as a reply so I can give you the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing "only" from your media query. Also make sure you've added the viewport meta tag to the head of your webpage `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Answer (score 6):

You have not posted your full source code.
But I 'll bet you've forgotten the **viewport** meta tag

Just put this inside your html `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

For more infos check this site:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: You are right, so I gave you the upvote; but somebody already beat you to it. Thank you though, its a mistake I will never make again; lost too much time on it.

Comment: @Frosty619 Actually this guy provided the right answer first.

Comment: Please look at the comments section, user2867288 provided the answer before as a comment.

Comment: I spent an hour trying to figure out whether I was using bootstrap wrong. I'll never forget this again. Thanks.